# Impact of below URL structure for eCommerce Site (in terms of SEO)

Tags: seo, url

Currently we are thinking of two possible URL structures for Products page and Product Detail Page and which one should we go with ?

1st Approach:

```
/products/ - Displays Products
/product/<product-slug> - Display Product Details
/product/ - Redirect to Products (Can someone shed light on redirecting
            directory but not pages underneath it, Is this acceptable?)
```

2nd Approach:

```
/products/ - Display Products
/products/product/<product-slug> - Display Product Details
```

We like 1st approach as it makes URL shorter and easy to remember/type but concerned about redirect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `/products/` for the main page and `/products/*` for item pages.
You're just complicating things unnecessarily. Unless there's more reasoning you're not bringing up.

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself this: *Would it make sense for Google/Yahoo!/Bing to rank one higher than the other?*

Or, alternatively, *As a search user, would I want Google/Yahoo!/Bing to rank one higher than the other?*

If the answer is "no", then the search engines probably came to the same conclusions as well.

This doesn't preclude some algorithmic quirks due to implementation causing one to have a slight advantage over the other in a particular search engine, but there's still no sense in website owners obsessing over microoptimizations like these, since:

- search algorithms are constantly changing, evolving and being improved upon; any such unintentional biases aren't liable to persist
- quirks in one engine could very well be balanced out by the opposite behavior in another (or in the same engine 2 months from now)
- it diverts energy from much more valuable/influential ranking factors

It's much better to invest in value-add improvements that have much more significant and longterm SEO benefits.

That said, `/products/product/<product-slug>` is pretty useless.

---

**Edit:**

The same applies to redirects. Google won't penalize you for redirects so long as you're using them correctly. If `/products/` 301 redirects to `/product/`, then there will be no penalty. It's the proper way to maintain canonicity when you want users to be able to access a document from multiple URLs.

Redirecting the parent directory but not the URLs under it won't have any impact on SEO, only usability. Users may type `/products/<product-slug>` expecting to go to `/product/<product-slug>` and instead get a 404. Though, as usual, poor usability can end up indirectly affect SEO since this could cause you to lose some backlinks (as well as sales).